# Using pgfplots, how do I arrange my data matrix for a surface plot so that each cell in the matrix is plotted as a square?

Tags: pgfplots

I have a matrix of size MxN and I want to make a surface plot directly from above so that each cell in the matrix is drawn as a square. None of the pgfplots shaders really do what I want, since they draw squares *between* the cells of the matrix (i.e. a 3x3 matrix ends up as 2x2 cells when plotted). The example hopefully makes it clearer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
        0 0 0
        0 1 1
        0 2 2

        1 0 3
        1 1 4
        1 2 5

        2 0 6
        2 1 7
        2 2 8
}\data

\begin{document}
\foreach \shader in {interp, flat, flat corner} {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        title={\texttt{\shader}},
        title style={
                at={(0.5, 1.5)},
                anchor=north,
        },
        width=.3\linewidth,
        view={0}{90},
        colormap/hot2,
        colorbar horizontal,
        colorbar style={
                at={(0.5, 1.02)},
                anchor=south,
                xticklabel pos=upper,
        },
]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=\shader] table {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I arrange my data so that each cell in the matrix is drawn as a separate cell in the output?

**EDIT**: I realised after entering the question that the answer is very simple, so I'll just answer this myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the `flat corner` plot in the question, it becomes obvious that one solution is to use `flat corner` and simply add an extra dummy row and an extra dummy column to the table. Their actual values will not influence the plot since `flat corner` uses only the value from the point which *is* inside the original matrix.

I am still interested in knowing other solutions, however, as the pgfplots manual specifies that "it is not defined which vertex is used here", making it a somewhat unstable solution to rely on the fact that it *appears* to use the point that I want.

Comment: This is an old feature request for pgfplots. I remember that it was not immediately clear how to switch from "vertex representation" to "cell representation" (i.e. how to interprete every data matrix as "cell representation") and I postponed the implementation.

Comment: I can live with the dummy row&column, but I'd really like to see the behaviour defined....

Answer (score 7):

Using the `matrix plot*` feature of PGFPlots v1.13 should exactly do what you want ([see section 4.6.12 on page 164 of the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=164)).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.13,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis on top,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=2,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=2,
            enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
            point meta=explicit,
            colormap/viridis,
            colorbar,
        ]
            \addplot [
                matrix plot*,
            ] table [meta index=2] {
                0 0 0
                0 1 1
                0 2 2

                1 0 3
                1 1 4
                1 2 5

                2 0 6
                2 1 7
                2 2 8
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]