# Visualising a matrix as an image, or specifying directly values for segments rather than for vertices

Tags: pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using pgfplots, how do I arrange my data matrix for a surface plot so that each cell in the matrix is plotted as a square?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73640/using-pgfplots-how-do-i-arrange-my-data-matrix-for-a-surface-plot-so-that-each)

I'm trying to use `pgfplots` to visualise a matrix using `\addplot3[surf]` and `view={0}{90}`. However, `pgfplots` colours each segment based on the value at the vertices, so that input coordinates in a `3x3`-matrix result in only 2*2=4 coloured segments:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
    width=4cm,
    height=4cm,
    colorbar right]
\addplot3[surf] coordinates {
    (0,0,0) (0,1,1) (0,2,2)

    (1,0,1) (1,1,2) (1,2,4)

    (2,0,2) (2,1,4) (2,2,8)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: Illustration of unwanted behaviour]

Is there a way to specify the colours of the segments directly for an image-view of a matrix?

Comment: I already wrote the question, then discovered it's a duplicate, however, having a duplicate question may make it easier for others to find it.